# Shall I use continuous or simple in this example

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

I am  waiting for a parcel because it has still not arrived. I mailed the seller and he wrote me that in fact he had written a wrong address .Now I am writing to him a new  email asking "what do we do now or what are we doing now "

I think the first one is better (after reading the difference between these expressions).

Am I right thinking the first one is better in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  "What do we do?" or perhaps with a modal: "What can we do? / What should we do? / What will we do?".  You not asking about the actions that you are currently taking, so "What are we doing?" is odd, but "What are you doing?" is possible.

You might be more assertive  "What are you going to do to fix this?".  Or you could give your suggestion "I want you to make me a refund / send me a replacement."